# Is there anyway to encrypt POST/GET variables before sending them?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm creating a simple security protocol for a website. In the login form, the user inputs their username and password. However, when the information is sent as $_GET or $_POST it has no security at all, e.g: http://www.mysite.com/sendinfo.php?user=blah&pass=password123 . Is there anyway to encrypt data clientside before sending it to the server? Thank you!

Comment: NEVER send passwords in the query string!

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/form-encryption

Comment: @KingCrunch How should I send the information then?

Comment: as POST, querystring variables will be cached by proxies, browser histories and what not.

Comment: Use SSL if you need a secure login and then generate a cookie or something so logged in users can be tracked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want guaranteed encryption without requiring client side code the only mechanism is SSL (i.e. an `https:` URL).